# cannot print Spark's RDD[Array]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I wrote an implementation for FuzzyCMeans algorithm in Apache Spark's MLlib, but for some reason when I try to print the output, the system stuck.

This is my input:

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
> data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:29
scala> data.collect().foreach{ point =>  println(point)  
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.2
9.0 9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1 9.1
9.2 9.2 9.2
```

But when I try to print the output after I run my algorithm, It get stuck:

The size of the output should be 6 (same as input's)

```
scala> val clusters = FuzzyCMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
> clusters: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.FuzzyCMeansModel = org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.FuzzyCMeansModel@31934160

scala> val ret = clusters.predictMatrix(parsedData)
> ret: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] = MapPartitionsRDD[17] at map at FuzzyCMeansModel.scala:276
scala> ret.collect().foreach{ point =>  println(point.deep.mkString(" "))  
> STUCK.....
```

}

Even if I try to count the RDD[Array], I get the same result:

```
val ret = clusters.predictMatrix(parsedData)
ret: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] = MapPartitionsRDD[11] at map at FuzzyCMeansModel.scala:276
scala> ret.count
> STUCK
```

Comment: The moment when you execute the `collect` method, you are moving all data and if it is big and the network is slow, then it might take time. It might be your case.

Answer (score 0):

The point where you run `collect` or `count` is when Spark starts running your prediction code. So it's not necessarily stuck, it's just working.

Look at the Spark status UI (port 4040) to see what exactly is going on. It will tell you whether progress is being made or not. You can also look at the executor and the driver logs to understand the situation better. You can print stuff from your code and see it in the executor logs to get more insight into what your code is doing.

Comment: You sure about that? I thought that because I get return value after I run clusters.predictMatrix, this action is finished successfully and I only have problem printing the values.
If that is the case, maybe my predict code is buggy.

Comment: It depends on what `predictMatrix` is exactly doing. But `count` getting stuck is a pretty strong indicator that some part of `predictMatrix` is not finished yet. RDD operations are lazy. Check the status page, it will answer everything.